# Как защитить логин и пароль, не используя SSL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Как защитить логин и пароль, не используя SSL?

Comment: Хотите защитить логин и пароль - не отправляйте логин/пароль. Отправляйте результат односторонней функции от имени-пароля.

Comment: @KoVadim, это не защита. Если кто-то перехватит хэш, он его же и пошлёт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На клиенте и на сервере обговорить шифрование, обмениваться данными в зашифрованном виде.

На вакуумный вопрос - вакуумный ответ.

Comment: То есть можно, например, самому взять алгоритм RES и реализовать его?